# Jquery selector alternative for parent.next.next

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following html structure that gets repeated as rows in a table

```
<div class='class1'>  <input type="checkbox" id="some_id" checked> </div>
<div class='class2'>   <label> Some Label </label> </div>
<div class='class3'>  Some Text </div>
```

When a checkbox is selected, I get the text assoicated with it using the jquery selector

```
this.$('#some_id').parent().next().next();
```

Is there a better way of achieving this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.class3').text();
```

or

```
$('#some_id').parent().siblings('.class3').text();
```

or try this:

```
$('#some_id').parent().nextAll().eq(1).text();
```